# How to extract a string that both matches some pattern and rests between two other strings

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Sorry if this is a duplicate.. it's not clear to me from what's already available on SO how to perform this specific task..

My goal is to find the filename of a zipped file inside some html code.  The filename is inside an `<a href=...>` html block, so it's easy for a human to find.

Here's some code to reproduce what i'm looking at:

```
# character vector with two strings from my html file
string.examples <-
    c("ANES Time Series Cumulative Data File</b><br /><a href=\"../cdf/cdf.htm\"> Study Page</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../cdf/cdf_errata.htm\">Errata</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdf.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-ascii']);\">Download ascii data files  <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfpor.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-por']);\">Download .por file  <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;August 25, 2011 version </td></tr>", 
    "ANES 2012 Time Series Study</b><br /><a href=\"../anes_timeseries_2012/anes_timeseries_2012.htm\">Study Page</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../anes_timeseries_2012/anes_timeseries_2012_errata.htm\">Errata</a>&nbsp; |  &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-ascii']);\">Download ascii data files <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_sav.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-sav']);\">Download .sav file</a> <a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_sav.zip\"><img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;July 1, 2013 version<br />"
)
```

Buried deep in the first line, there's the text `<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip\"`  and in the second line, there's the text `<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip\"`

From these two lines, I would want to extract `../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip` and  `../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip` because they contain the text `dta.zip`and because they *start* with `<a href=\"` and then end with `\"`

I'd want something where:

```
x <- some.regex.function( string.examples )
```

produces a character vector of length two with..

```
> x
[1] "../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip"                     "../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip"
```

Comment: All files have dta.zip in common?

Comment: `gsub("(.*a href=\\\")(.*dta\\.zip)(.*)$", "\\2", string.examples)`?

Comment: @Arun dammit i am so lousy a regular expressions.. can you put that as the answer and i'll mark it correct?  thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @LefterisBab yep.  Arun solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I assume that the patterm you're looking for starts after `a href=\"` and ends with `dta.zip`. So the idea is to use greedy search to get through all `a href` up until `dta.zip`. Also, we capture each portion and replace the searched string with the required capture.

```
gsub("(.*a href=\\\")(.*dta\\.zip)(.*)$", "\\2", string.examples)
```

The `.*a href=\\\"` as mentioned before "greedy" searches for the pattern (had to escape \ and "). Then by doing `.*data\\.zip`, we restrict the greedy search to not go beyond the point where we require. Also this is the pattern we'are interested in. So, we make sure to capture that as well. Then the rest is obvious. The replace pattern then is the second capture.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. You can replace the `a href` to `href` if you expect to have `a onmouseover href` and other variations.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This regex will:

- find the anchor tag href values where the value ends with `dta.zip`
- avoid problematic edge cases

`<a(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=\\(['"]?)((?:(?!\1(?:\s|\/>|>)).)*dta\.zip)\\)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/a>`

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the first line has some difficult edge cases

```
<a onmouseup="" onmouseover=' href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/DontFindMe_dta.zip\" ; if (6 > x) { funRotate(href); } ' href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/DifficultToFind_dta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-dta']);\">

"ANES Time Series Cumulative Data File</b><br /><a href=\"../cdf/cdf.htm\"> Study Page</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../cdf/cdf_errata.htm\">Errata</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdf.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-ascii']);\">Download ascii data files  <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfpor.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-por']);\">Download .por file  <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;August 25, 2011 version </td></tr>", 
    "ANES 2012 Time Series Study</b><br /><a href=\"../anes_timeseries_2012/anes_timeseries_2012.htm\">Study Page</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../anes_timeseries_2012/anes_timeseries_2012_errata.htm\">Errata</a>&nbsp; |  &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-ascii']);\">Download ascii data files <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_sav.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-sav']);\">Download .sav file</a> <a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_sav.zip\"><img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;<a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;July 1, 2013 version<br />ac
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <a onmouseup="" onmouseover=' href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/DontFindMe_dta.zip\" ; if (6 > x) { funRotate(href); } ' href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/DifficultToFind_dta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-dta']);\">

"ANES Time Series Cumulative Data File</b><br /><a href=\"../cdf/cdf.htm\"> Study Page</a>
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = ../data/anes_timeseries_2012/DifficultToFind_dta.zip


[1][0] = <a href=\"../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/cdf-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>
[1][1] = "
[1][2] = ../data/cdf/anes_cdfdta.zip


[2][0] = <a href=\"../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip\" onClick=\"javascript: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/downloads/2012TS-dta']);\">Download .dta file <img src=\"../../images/zip.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"23\" height=\"13\" /></a>
[2][1] = "
[2][2] = ../data/anes_timeseries_2012/anes2012TS_dta.zip
```

Comment: Nice. But did you write this regex manually? Or did you use some tool to write it ?

Comment: I wrote it manually in notepad, then I used an online regex tool to check that it worked as advertised.